# Scope variables not updating in navbar outside of ng-view in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a hard time trying to make a dynamically navbar in AngularJS.My scope variable I use to check whether a user is logged in or not is not changing in navbar, however it's value is changing in console or inside the ng-view.
Here is my index.html navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4" role="navigation" ng-controller="controllerlogin">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Gab's Store</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#/">Acasa</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#!/produse">Produse</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#!/despre">Despre</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#!/produsee/adaugareprodus">Adaugare produs</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0" ng-hide="logat">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="#!/login">{{logat}}</a>
      </form>
       <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0" ng-show="logat">
        <label>Welcome,{{loggedin.username}}!</label>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-success"  ng-init="Logout()">Log out</a>
      </form>
    </div>

  </nav>
```

Variable **logat** is used to store the value whether a user is logged in or not.Here is my controllerlogin file

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

 myApp.controller('controllerlogin', 
 ['$scope','$http','$location','$routeParams','$rootScope',
function($scope,$http ,$location,$routeParams,$rootScope){
$scope.Login = function(){
$http.post('/api/login',$scope.userr).then(succesCallback,errorCallback);
function succesCallback(response){  
        console.log(response.data);
    $rootScope.loggedin = response.data;
    if($rootScope.loggedin.validity == "0")
    {
        $rootScope.logat = true;
        window.location.href = '#!/'

    }if($rootScope.loggedin.validity == "1"){
        $rootScope.logat = false;
        window.location.href = '#!/login'
    }
    if($rootScope.loggedin.validity == "2"){
        $rootScope.logat = false;
        window.location.href = '#!/login'
    }
}
function errorCallback(error){
    throw error;
}
}
```

}]);

The variable **validity** is used to check if a log in is successful or not(based on response from server).
And a part of code from my app.js file.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when('/',{
    controller:'controllertipproduse',
    templateUrl: 'views/Default.html'
})
.when('/produse',{
    controller:'controllerproduse',
    templateUrl: 'views/Produse.html'
})
.when('/login',{
    controller:'controllerlogin',
    templateUrl: 'views/Login.html'
})
```

Comment: Don't use `ng-controller` on nav

Comment: Ah ok I won't use it anymore, I didn't use it at first try but after I did almost everything I have read to check if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
   <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="#!/login">{{$root.logat}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using $scope instead of $rootScope.

Normally it is not advisable to use $rootScope for attaching angular variables.

Comment: At first try I was using $scope (and it wasn't working) and then I have read that it is better to use $rootScope cause it can be seen from any controller.